# Aggregate Queries Count is Wrong

Tags: soql

As per the Salesforce official [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm), For COUNT() or COUNT(fieldname) queries, limits are counted as one query row, unless the query contains a GROUP BY clause, in which case one query row per grouping is consumed.

But, above statement seems to be wrong:

```
System.debug('before === '+Limits.getQueries());
List<AggregateResult> aggr = [Select count(Name) From Account GROUP BY Id LIMIT 100];
System.debug('After ==== '+Limits.getQueries());
```

[image]

Any thoughts ?

Comment: What is the connection between the image you shared and the screenshot below it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limits.getQueries returns the number of query statements (i.e. the number of queries you've executed). You'll want to check Limits.getQueryRows instead.

---

```
System.debug('before === '+Limits.getQueryRows());
List<AggregateResult> aggr = [Select count(Name) From Account GROUP BY Id LIMIT 100];
System.debug('After ==== '+Limits.getQueryRows());
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, I misread the document ;)